# __callStatic proxy to non-static methods

Tags: php, proxy, static, static-methods, magic-methods

I am experimenting with `__callStatic` for a bit. My setup works fine but I was wondering, what if you want to proxy a static call to an existing method non-static method.

From what I have seen with Laravel's facade system, they kind of do the same. When I try it though I get this error message:

```
"Non-static method blablabla() should not be called statically"
```

It still tries to point directly to the method and seems to bypass the `__callStatic` whenever I call an existing method.

I know the __callStatic only runs on methods that can not be found in the class itself. But how could this be changed to proxy to my existing non-static methods?

**Edit:**

It just dawned on me that the Laravel facades actually contain no direct reference to the their classes but rather a container instance they can resolve. I guess this is how they actually get around doing this, because they methods actually don't exist on the facade?